# Is it possible to record the current position of the anchor in ARCore with Java and to upload the position again as an anchor after a new placement?

Tags: java, android, anchor, arcore

I am currently **writing an AR App with ARcore and Java**. Here I have to set an anchor point, move it and update the anchor again after the transitory movement. Unfortunately the last step does not work.

Is there a way to pick up the current position of the anchor and output it as an anchor again, so I can upload it.

I tried to take the position of the anchor and upload it again. Therefore I need the method anchor as input. I failed with the following code.

```
private synchronized void onUpdateButtonPressed() {

  Anchor anchor = AnchorNode.getAnchor();
  setNewAnchor(anchor);
  snackbarHelper.showMessage(getActivity(), "Update anchor..."); // reating a Hosted Anchor
  cloudAnchorManager.hostCloudAnchor(
          getArSceneView().getSession(), anchor, this::onHostedAnchorAvailable); // reating a Hosted Anchor
```

> error: non-static method getAnchor() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: So far your problem is not whether you can save anchor position (you **can** save both its world position and its local position, depending on what you need). `AnchorNode::getAnchor()` is an instance method, so first you should somehow get your hands on the instance of that. Your snippet doesn't provide me with any details regarding where you'd start though.